# Execute code after celery finishes a tasks

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm using Django 2.0, Python 3.6 and Celery 4.1

After celery is finishing a task, I want to execute a code that do an update in the database.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

1. Implement the code to update the db and run it at the end of your task.  You can implement your own implementation of [`on_success`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.on_success)
2. If you're executing many small tasks and need to do a cleanup task after, then using [`group`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) or [`chord`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords)  The latter is very useful, but requires you have a result store as part of your infrastructure.

Since you seem to just want to update the db after the task has completed, I'd go with #1

Comment: can you please provide  a starting code. I check on success and I don't know were to execute it, inside the tasks or a separate tasks outside the main task code

Comment: @user3541631 you don't execute the code inside `on_success`.  Celery task will do that for you automatically when the task successfully completes.    What I'm trying to say is write the code you want to update your db inside `on_success`

Comment: this is my problem I don't know how to call on_success, where to added, after my task or not, have decorators, this is why I asked you to give me a simple example; I on't understand very well from documentation

Comment: You DO NOT CALL `on_success`.  Celery does that for you.  You implement that method in your celery task.  If you google `celery on_success example`, you'll find a number of quality responses